# OrientDB - numbers in the class names

Tags: naming-conventions, orientdb, classname

When I'm trying to create a class, that it's name contains a number (ex., 3D-Printers), OrientDB refuses and answers (in Studio):

> Error parsing
>   query: CREATE CLASS 3D-Printers ^ Encountered "
>   FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL "3D "" at line 1, column 14. Was expecting
>   one of: TO ... VALUE ...

..etcetc

When trying to do the same from Java app with createVertexType, getting this exception:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OResponseProcessingException: Exception during response processing
>   ......
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3D-Printers"
>
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Just wondering - is it possible to use numbers in classes names somehow? And if not - what is the class naming convention in OrientDB? As I know, symbols . , / ' are restricted; but numbers?

using community edition 2.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrientDB uses the Java convention for class names, so you can use numbers, but not as first character.